# Which VisualStudio-Settings change CorFlags (32BITREQ)

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015, x86, corflags

which settings in Visual Studio are changing the CorFlags? Especially: Which settings i have to change to set/unset the 32BITREQ flag of my built .dll-file?

I know i can toggle the flaggs with VS Developer Command Prompt:

```
CorFlags /32BITREQ[-/+] MyDll.dll
```

but i want to change it in my project(with settings not code) so i dont have to do it manually.

Thx!

Comment: In short, set the target architecture to x86 (32-bit). Hard to imagine how you became aware of CorFlags values before you found this fundamental setting in the IDE! :-)

Comment: i already did.. that my output:
Version   : v4.0.30319
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 0x3
ILONLY    : 1
32BITREQ  : 1
32BITPREF : 0
Signed    : 0

Comment: Are you just saying that you have now answered your own question? Or do you still have a problem?

Comment: oh boy.. i had the solution right in front of me .. well thx tho

Comment: Solution to my problem: might help someone later.. the <Platform>-tag in one of my .csproj-files was not set to the right target platform.. at least i thought visual studio would do that if i change it in the settings.. i just manually changed the tag value with simple notpad to x86 (x64 or Any Cpu works aswell) ..